# How can I clear cached timezone information in .net 2.0?

Tags: .net, caching, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a sealed Windows XP embedded device which always boots up with the same windows settings. When my software starts up it needs to set the timezone of the machine to a user-configurable setting. Unfortunately, I've discovered that even though I'm updating the timezone, all of the methods in .net which retrieve the system time don't appear to pick up the changes.

A bit of digging suggests that in .net 3.5 and 4.0 there is a method to clear a cache: [system.timezoneinfo.clearcacheddata()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.clearcacheddata.aspx). I'm working with .net 2.0 though so how can I get around this in .net 2.0?

Is the only option to have a second piece of software running to set the timezone before the main application runs (re-loading the software appears to fix the issue)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET DateTime.Now returns incorrect time when time zone is changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296918/net-datetime-now-returns-incorrect-time-when-time-zone-is-changed)

Comment: definitely - I couldn't find anything on the subject when I searched!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind; I found [a solution that works](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/timezone-currenttimezone-doesnt-update-t2781997.html) all the way back to .net v1.0:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
```