# Using C#, how to clear a running application Cache to adopt timezone change?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timezone

***Description***

I have 2 running applications:

1. A C# based app I created to check if time or timezone was changed and sync the time with a device. (**APP1**)
2. An external/third party application that watches time to do data processing, as well as perform necessary task at a set time.(**APP2**)

There is also another app that checks timezone data from a Master Clock and executes on a fixed schedule. This app updates the timezone whenever the Master Clock sends a timezone update command.

I have configured **APP1** to clear it's own cache so that it would get the correct time (as asked [here by GregK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296918/net-datetime-now-returns-incorrect-time-when-time-zone-is-changed)). **APP1** is working correctly.

***Problem***

So when the timezone has changed, **APP2** execute it's scheduled tasks with delay because it is getting incorrect time.

***Question***

Is there a way to clear **APP2**'s cache or force it to adopt with the timezone change without restarting it?

Comment: Why not use UTC, and convert it to local time for each device? e.g. you have the time in UTC, then on the device you add/subtract the difference for the current time zone.

Comment: I have **APP1** running and getting the correct time. I did a work around to eliminate this issue on **APP1**. I have created tools (applications) that when executed will write the current time into a text file. That way, I can get correct time regardless whether the time zone has been changed or not. And because it is executed everytime **APP1** request for the current time, time zone cache will not persist in the application.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the developer of **APP2**. That is why I cannot do any modifications to it.

Comment: Then how are you going to clear APP2's cache, or otherwise force it? When you can't do any modifications to it.

Comment: That's my question. XD I was thinking that if there is/are Windows API(s) in which I can PInvoke to access process and then clear the TimeZone cache of the application.

Comment: No, this is done by the developer of that application. You will need to either restart that application, so that it loads the new correct data, or contact the developers of the application.

Comment: That's what I have figured. Windows applications does not respond the timezone change when not handled properly. Now I will need to make a work-around for it. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I have made.

**APP1** will handle the time change. It will store the current timezone the server is in. And then when when the timezone changes, it will store the time into a variable then restore the last timezone used and update the current time using the new time stored in variable. That way, the server could adopt with the time change even though the timezone will not change.

[Here's how](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7694491-f077-4c60-8585-979f4168d958/datetime-is-not-reflected-instantly-after-changing-the-timezone-from-my-application?forum=csharpgeneral) to get the correct time after a timezone change.

```
protected override void OnClosed ( EventArgs e )
{
   base.OnClosed(e);
   SystemEvents.TimeChanged -= SystemEvents_TimeChanged;
}

protected override void OnLoad ( EventArgs e )
{
   base.OnLoad(e);
   SystemEvents.TimeChanged += SystemEvents_TimeChanged;
}

void SystemEvents_TimeChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
}

private void timer1_Tick ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Another reference for [getting the current timezone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
Console.WriteLine(localZone.StandardName);
```

That way, you don't need to restart the application. Cheers!