# Why would DateTime.UTCNow be wrong?

Tags: .net

We use DateTime.UTCNow from the client machine to determine whether or not to re-up a token generated from the server before it expires.  We found ourselves in an unexpected situation when this date comparison always suggested that the token was expired as soon as it was generated.  By putting in some logging information on the client machine, I found that DateTime.UTCNow was returning a value that was off by an hour.  This is a corporate machine that prevents users from even opening up the clock controls and the symptom only shows up on a small number of users' machines.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to where to begin tracking down what offset the clock?

Comment: Sounds like daylight-savings time. Do all those computers have the same regional settings?

Comment: `UTCNow` isn't wrong but your machine may have the wrong timezone settings. Use DateTimeOffset.Now to get the current DateTimeOffset value. I suspect the server and the failing machines have a different timezone from that of the server

Comment: Have you checked whether the clocks on those machines are actually right? Tangentially related, are the users in Russia, Egypt or Chile?

Comment: @Martijn has a point - Russia changed timezone rules yet again last year and does *not* follow DST changes. The rule change was delivered as a Windows update but either the server or the machines do not have it

Comment: And so did Chile. And Egypt decided they would change it, but reversed the decision.

Comment: It is normal for [DateTime.Now to be off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296918/net-datetime-now-returns-incorrect-time-when-time-zone-is-changed/297189#297189).  Not normal for DateTime.UtcNow, that comes straight out of the operating system, underlying call is GetSystemTimeAsFileTime().  Having the machine locked up without anybody being able to tweak it and no way for timezone updates to be delivered through Windows Update is the most likely explanation.